# Updating to Xcode 7 and keeping 6.4

Tags: xcode7, xcode6.4

I have Xcode 6.4 and want to update to Xcode 7. But I want to keep the 6.4 version working and have both as well. Does this work? And if so, how? I am running OS X 10.10.5 if this matters.

Comment: Why do you want to keep the old version?

Comment: In case something went wrong. I have a lot of external libraries that might need fixing! I want to keep the programming on while fixing if it is going to take time! Just in case you know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do such a thing by renaming `Xcode.app` in `Xcode6.app` from the `/Application` directory then download Xcode 7 from the App Store.

Edit: Thanks to the feedback from HannaB, we need to copy the `Xcode6.app` somewhere else before downloading the new version otherwise it will overwrite the current version. After the installation of the new version, you can safely move `Xcode6.app` back to the `/Application` folder

Comment: I can't find Xcode.dmg! is it the same as Xcode.app?

Comment: My bad, it's Xcode.app ! I edited my post to correct this mistake.

Comment: okay so it worked. but note that the old file should be copied somewhere else because the update overwrites the new one and then recopy the old file and it should work fine. just please update your answer! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Done!